# Make fixed content area without effecting sidebars

Tags: html, css

I want to make content area min width fixed. I have two sidebars and content area. One sidebar can hide by a button.Other one should always visible.When first sidebar is hidden content area should expand. But unless its hidden content should be fixed for given static size. Currently when I give content min-width static value, right sidebar disappears in low resolution. Ignore sidebar hide part. I want to avoid second sidebar overflow by content in low resolution problem.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hydride/nspn2vk7/)

```
<body>
<div id="main-container" class="clearfix">
    <aside id="sidebar-main" class="sidebar"> 
    </aside>
    <aside id="sidebar-sec" class="sidebar">
    </aside>
    <div id="main" class="clearfix">
    </div>
</div>
</body>

body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#main-container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
#sidebar-main {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 240px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#sidebar-sec {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
#main {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width:709px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hydride/nspn2vk7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have changed the order of divs and used `table` layout.

```css
body {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#main-container {
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background-color:red;
display: table;
}
aside{
display: table-cell;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
#sidebar-main {
width: 240px;
    min-width: 240px;
background-color:blue;
}
#sidebar-sec {
width: 400px;
min-width: 400px;
}
#main {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
min-width:709px;
display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main-container" class="clearfix">

<aside id="sidebar-main" class="sidebar"> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint pariatur eligendi saepe ullam incidunt, nemo commodi! Expedita, alias nihil tempore. Quibusdam omnis, eum minus mollitia quas nostrum repellat ipsa.
</aside>

<div id="main" class="clearfix">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint pariatur eligendi saepe ullam incidunt, nemo commodi! Expedita, alias nihil tempore. Quibusdam omnis, eum minus mollitia quas nostrum repellat ipsa.
</div>
<aside id="sidebar-sec" class="sidebar">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint pariatur eligendi saepe ullam incidunt, nemo commodi! Expedita, alias nihil tempore. Quibusdam omnis, eum minus mollitia quas nostrum repellat ipsa.
</aside>
</div>
</body>
```

Updated Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nspn2vk7/1/

Comment: This works as expected. Just for my knowledge can you tell me is there a method to achieve this without using table and table cell approach?

Comment: One issue with the CSS is that the total width needed for `#main-container` is `width:1349px`. Not `width:100%`.  So you can solve this simply by adding a width or min-width of 1350px to the `#main-container`.  - Check the updated fiddle - [https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nspn2vk7/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nspn2vk7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit - Check out this question:**

[Fixed sidebar and fluid content area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846338/fixed-sidebar-and-fluid-content-area?rq=1)

It's not the same but it might be similar enough to help. If you get time and you don't already know jQuery you should look into it, once you get past learning the beginning of it it actually makes a lot of things much easier.

---

I think that might be accomplished best if you use jQuery to change the CSS of the content area. The JSFiddle that you linked isn't really working according to what you're describing so I can't give you the exact code to use but it might look something like this.

```
$("#sidebar-sec").click(function(){
    $("content_area").css("width", "width goes here");
});
```

Something along those lines might be easier than trying to do it with only CSS especially if you're having problems with it. You could also use it to hide the sidebar in the first place if you add something like this:

```
$("#sidebar-sec").hide();
```

Comment: I'm looking for a css way. But thanks. In jsfiddle its hides second side bar and content takes full width. Thats what I want to avoid

Comment: I found something that will probably help I'm just going to edit it in to my answer.